# C# Upcasting / Polymorphism Issue

Tags: c#, polymorphism, downcast, upcasting

I believe this question is fairly basic but I am having trouble finding an answer to this question. In C# let's say I have 3 classes: `A, B, C`

B derives from A

C derives from B

Now, if I wanted a list or array of objects of type class A but wanted the array to be able to house objects of type B and C this is no problem... I could do something like this:

```
A[] myArrayofAtypes;
```

However let's say I make the first element of this array of type C. If type C has a variable defined in its class definition that ONLY exists in class C's class definition... how do I access that variable from the array? I can't just do `A[0].MyVariableGetter` as that variable does not exist in the base class, A.

Any suggestions?

Comment: creating an array of A[]  and holding everything there isn't polymophism

Comment: My question had factors pertaining to polymorphism so I figured marking that as a category for the question was appropriate. Also, I never said creating an array of A[] and holding everything there was polymophism.

Comment: your question is about casting and inheritance.. once you check the object's type you aren't polymorphic

Comment: Would it make you feel better if I said inclusion polymorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **downcast** it:

```
C c = (C)myArrayofAtypes[0];
var v = c.MyVariableGetter;
```

Comment: Is downcasting processing intensive if it is done a lot? I mean, imagine an array of 100 elements and every element needs downcasted all on succession to access their details... Is this a bad thing for processing time / resources?

Comment: 100 elements? nope. More than few ten thousands? Possibly.

Comment: @BradMash check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305755/what-is-the-performance-hit-with-downcasting).

Comment: If I implement what you did king.code then to actually update the array element so it gets the updated object at position [0] in the array do I need to then do myArrayofAtypes[0] = c ? Or do I have to upcast again and then do myArrayofAtypes[0] = c ?

Comment: @BradMash since your array holds A references you have to always downcast. I mean, if you do this `myArrayofAtypes[0] = (C)myArrayofAtypes[0];`, you are downcasting and then upcasting again.

Comment: I guess what I mean is... 

C c = (C)myArrayofAtypes[0];

c.MyVariableGetter = 15;

myArrayofAtypes[0] = c; // if this does not work, do I need to do this: 

// myArrayofAtypes[0] = (A)c;

Comment: @BradMash upcasting is implicit, you can do it but you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate your help... Working with ColdFusion all day every day has made my OOP a little rusty. Appreciate your time

Comment: @BradMash In your example you don't need to do `myArrayofAtypes[0] = c;`, because you only modified a property of `c` the `myArrayofAtypes[0]` was also modified because both variables `c` and `myArrayofAtypes[0]` point to the same object (Unless `A`, `B`, and `C` are stucts instead of classes, but that would mean you have a mutable stuct, which should not be done.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast it to type c and access the member.

```
If (arr[i] is c)
{
    ((C)arr[0]).member = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting as 'king.code' has suggested like this I would use these pretty C# operators which are 'is' and 'as'.

```
public void CallIfTypeC(A a)
{
    if (a is C)
    {
        C c = a as C;
        c.DoAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense but let me ask you this... can I do the downcasting, update A[0] in my example (update this instance's class C specific variables) and have that instance updated in the array? Does that make sense?